# How to revert to Unity from Xfce desktop at Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, xfce

I used Ubuntu 14.04 in my PC. Now after some installations I have the Xfce desktop. I want to revert to [Unity](https://unity.ubuntu.com/) again.

Now I have [the Xfce desktop](http://www.unixmen.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/XFCE.png) and I want to revert to [the Unity desktop](http://cdn4.thetechjournal.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/ubuntu1404.jpg).

*So how can I do that?*

Comment: @djcrashdummy: Could you please review [my edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/640272/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits in the future? **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

In most cases the following command should work:

```
sudo apt-get purge xfconf xfce4-utils xfwm4 xfce4-session thunar xfdesktop4 exo-utils xfce4-panel xfce4-terminal
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
```

If not, first get a list of packages installed by xfce. Run:

> `dpkg --get-selections | grep xfce`

Look at the installed packages and then purge them by:

```
sudo apt-get purge <package1><package2><package3>
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: @user42577:  As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**